# How to execute a JQuery selector after dom objects are rendered complete in a search display template

Tags: jquery, search-results, display-template

I want to run a JQuery selector after all divs in Search Display Template (e.g. Item_Person.html) finished rendering.

My funcs always seems run straight after master page is rendered, but it still too early because all doms in search display template haven't rendered yet.

using setTimeout(func,1000) can make it work, but it is quite a cheat.

Comment: hmm, I have not tried but I remember the display template file consist JS. Can you put your code in the template file?

Comment: Did that, and trying window.load or sort of thing, still load too early.  SetTimeout(func,0) would work. But would like to know if there is actually a way SharePoint has provided through JSOM class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharePoint provides a hook for this called AddPostRenderCallback. All you need to do is define it in your template.

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sharepoint_quick_reads/2013/08/01/sharepoint-2013-customize-display-template-for-content-by-search-web-part-cswp-part-2/

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right path thinking about `window.onload`

But you want an **onload event** on content ***inside*** your Display Template

Available elements you can set on `onload` event on:
**body, frame, iframe, img, input type="image", link, script, style**
source: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp

#### So your DisplayTemplate could use:

```
<div id='myDisplayTemplate'>
    <img src="_layouts/images/blank.gif" onload="loadedTemplate()">
</div>

<script>
function loadTemplate() {
    console.info("Image INSIDE" , this.parentNode.id , "loaded");
}
</script>
```

You are not displaying an image.. you only want the `onload` event

You could even do without an image src and use the `onerror` event, but that approach might have edge-cases with problems

This trick is also used when you put HTML/JS in a Calculated Column,
see docs: https://www.365csi.nl/vm365com/#/How